# How do I replace the last occurrence in a string in C manually?

Tags: c, str-replace

I'm studying some basic functions for my C midterm and I realized I copied down my instructor's example incorrectly. I'm probably just too tired to think this through right now and a little push would be greatly appreciated.

```
void replace_last(char s[], int oldc, int newc){
    size_t i, pos-1; /* I have no idea why I wrote pos-1. I know I need it though */
        for(i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++){
             if(s[i] == oldc)
                 pos == i;
             if(pos != -1)
                 s[pos] = newc;
         }
}
```

Comment: "I know I need it though" - I really don't think you _need_ a syntax error in your code.

Comment: I think , there should be pos= - 1; because just pos-1 evaluate to rvalue which is not assigned to anything .. i think it's initialization of pos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void replace_last(char s[], int oldc, int newc){
   size_t i, pos = -1;
   for(i = 0; s[i]; i++)
      if(s[i] == oldc)
         pos = i;
   if(pos != -1)
      s[pos] = newc;
}
```

So your copied code had three problems: `pos-1`, `pos == i`, and thirdly, the logic `if(pos != -1) s[pos] = newc;` needs to be *outside* the loop.

**Edit:** Just to round-off the answer, the "non-manual" way of doing this would be, for example:

```
void replace_last(char s[], int oldc, int newc) {
   if (strrchr(s, oldc))
      *strrchr(s, oldc) = newc;
}
```

(You could, if you wished, save the return of `strrchr()` of in a temporary pointer, to avoid the second call to `strrchr(),` but this is probably unnecessary:  gcc with `-O1` does this for you automatically.)

Comment: That solved everything. Thank you. I deserve to get this question wrong for not taking proper notes.

Answer (score 2):

Inside Ist if statement you are doing `pos==i` that should be `pos=i`

because `pos==i` is conditional statement and `pos = i` is assignment

```
void replace_last(char s[], int oldc, int newc){
    size_t i, pos=-1; /* I have no idea why I wrote pos-1. I know I need it though */
        for(i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++){
             if(s[i] == oldc)
                 pos = i;
             if(pos != -1)
                 s[pos] = newc;
         }
}
```

I think you want to replace the `oldc` with `newc` by finding the position of `oldc` and then changing the value of `pos` and in the same iteration you are doing `s[pos]=new` which will replace `oldc` wtih `newc`

The code is fine now.. you can run it or dry run and check it

Comment: Thanks Omkant...that fixed part of the problem. Now it replaces all instances of the letter however. Entirely likely I buggered it up more.

Comment: @SpaceJesus : What r u intended is not clear at all and what is pos btw

Comment: pos is supposed to track the current position in the string. Basically if I pass in oreo, o, m - my string should be changed to orem

Comment: I have given the code and explanation .. i have just dry run it it's working fine ..check it and accept the answer if agree

Answer (score 2):

Line number : 5
`pos==i` should be replaced with `pos=i`